# For which integers $x$ is $x(x+45)$ a square?

Tags: number-theory

I am working with the solutions in integers of another equation, and I have arrived to the problem of find all solutions $(x,t)$ of $x^2 +45x= t^2 $, but I don´t know how to solve this kind of equations.
What part of number theory does apply here?

Answer (score 5):

Note that we need

$$\left(x + \frac{45}{2}\right)^2 - \frac{2025}{4} = t^2$$
$$(2x + 45)^2 - 2025 = (2t)^2$$
$$(2x + 45)^2 - (2t)^2 = 2025$$
$$(2x + 45 + 2t)(2x + 45 - 2t) = 2025$$

from which you can test the $15$ possible (positive) decompositions of $2025$ into two integers to find out the possible values of $x$ and $t$ produced.

Answer (score 3):

If $x$ and $x+45$ are coprime, both mst be squares. Let $x=m^2$ and $x+45=n^2$. Then
$$n^2-m^2=(n+m)(n-m)=45$$
So $m+n$ is a divisor of $45$ greater than $\sqrt{45}$, that is $m+n$ is $9$, $15$ or $45$.

If $\gcd(x,x+45)=3$ then $x/3$ and $(x+45)/3$ are squares. Let $m^2=x/3$ and $(x+45)/3=n^2$. Then
$$n^2-m^2=(n+m)(n-m)=15$$
and $n+m$ is $5$ or $15$.

Do the same with the remainding divisors of $45$.

Answer (score 2):

$x^2<x^2+45x<(x+23)^2$ so there are basically $22$ numbers to check.

By assuming $x\geq 1$ we can further refine to $x^2+45x>(x+5)^2$

Comment: ok, I forgot this technique, thank´s!

Comment: This assumes $x\ge 0$ but there are solutions with $x<0$, for instance, $x=-60$.